# Do I need to use absolute CSS positioning for this layout or can it be simply achieved with CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

This is the layout I'm talking about:

[image]

I traced these red grid lines using GIMP. Do you think that it can be done just by using CSS grid and positioning each element into their proper grid block?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute; top: -30px(example)`or negative margins `margin-top -30px (sample)`.

Comment: I was interested if it could be achieved with vanilla CSS grid.

Comment: Yes it can achieve it with vanilla CSS.  @ZoltanKing